# Mongoose search query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm implementing a search through a Mongodb database using Mongoose. On the client side, I have:

```
var searchQuery = {
            title: ($('#responseTitle').val()),
            text: ($('#responseKeywords').val())
        };

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../../api/threads",
        data: searchQuery,
        success: function(data){
            prefetchedResponses = data;
            loadResponseBrowser();
        }
    })
```

On the server-side, I have:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    Response.find(req.query, function(err, foundResponses){
    ...
```

This works, but only returns matches with the exact fields. I want to implement a regex-type search. However, I can't decide whether to do it on the client or server-side. On the server side, it would involve iterating through each field of `req.query` and appending the necessary properties to enable for regex search. On the client side, it would be easier, by just constructing `title` and `text` with those properties pre-defined. However, doing it on the client-side seems wrong to me, since the backend could change at any time.

Is there a third alternative in Mongoose that would allow me to apply regex to all fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No third alternative, you have to define your regex in client side :

```
var searchQuery = {
        title: {$regex: ($('#responseTitle').val()),  $options: "i"}, 
        text: {$regex: ($('#responseKeywords').val()), $options: "i"}
    };
```

Or in server side

```
for(var i in req.query)
{
    req.query[i] =  {$regex: req.query[i], $options: "i"};
}
Response.find(req.query, ....
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass regular expressions to mongoose. This is easily done be doing the following:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    var regexQuery = {
      title: new RegExp(req.query.title, 'i')
      text: new RegExp(req.query.text, 'i')
    }
    Response.find(regexQuery, function(err, foundResponses){
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but like I said, it involves iterating over each field

Answer (score 1):

Use `POST` method instead of `GET` method.

**client side javascript**

```
var searchQuery = {
    title: ($('#responseTitle').val()),
    text: ($('#responseKeywords').val())
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../api/threads",
    data: searchQuery,
    success: function(data) {
        prefetchedResponses = data;
        loadResponseBrowser();
    }
})
```

**server side javaScript**

```
router.post('/threads', function(req, res, next) {
    var searchTitle = req.body.title;
    var searchText = req.body.text;
    var regexValue1 = '^' + searchTitle;
    var regexValue2 = '^' + searchText;
    var queryOptions = {
        $and: [{
            searchTitle: {
                '$regex': regexValue1,
                '$options': 'i'
            }
        }, {
            text: {
                '$regex': regexValue2,
                '$options': 'i'
            }
        }]
    }
    var promise = Response.find(queryOptions);
    promise.then(function(data) {
        if (data) {
            return res.status(200).json(data);
        } else {
            return res.status(422).json('No data')
        }
    });
    promise.catch(function(error) {
        return res.status(500).json(error);
    });
});
```